# Is it possible to interpret javascript code placed inside an html tag?

Tags: javascript, html, eval, pre

I want to use HTML to document an algorithm. This will be a local file, so there aren't any security issues.

The idea is to have a `<pre>` tag containing javascript code. Then, when the page is loaded, a `<canvas>` element will be rendered according to the the code contents, which must be evaluated.

I believe this would use some sort of `eval()` of the `innerHtml` property of the `<pre>` tag, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Seems reasonable.  Try it and see if it works.  If it doesn't work, come back to us with the issue, and we'll see if we can help you make it work.

Comment: @BenBarden I admit I could have done it myself, but I looked around SO and didn't find anything similar. Hopefully, other beginners can come back to find some help. :o)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can indeed run code inside a `<pre>` using `innerHTML` to get the code and then `eval()`. I've added the HTML5 `contenteditable` attribute to our `<pre>` so we can edit it like a `<textarea>`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/t5W9L/2/)

[image]

**HTML**

```
<pre id="code" contenteditable>var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(10,10);
context.lineTo(40,40);
context.stroke();</pre>
<button id="run">Run</button>
<canvas width="400" height="300" id="canvas"></canvas>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var button = document.getElementById('run');
button.onclick = function () {
    var code = document.getElementById('code').innerHTML;
    eval(code);
};
```

Comment: Exactely what I needed: a piece of minimally working code to build upon. Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry, I had one problem: If I try to put a for loop along with the `pre` tag, I keep getting errors like "missing ) after for-loop control", or "missing ; in for loop initializer". Do you know how I could solve this? (sort of this: http://jsfiddle.net/keTd9/2/)